# CollectionViewCell sublayer not updated on iOS 10

Tags: calayer, ios10

before iOS 10, setting my CollectionViewCell sublayer contents was working well, on iOS 10, some cells are not refreshed.

I tried to force cell/layer refresh but nothing changed.

I found that invalidating collectionViewLayout of my collectionView, refreshes all my cells and layer contents is refreshed too.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused the problem.
In willDisplayCell I was clearing layer.contents, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath I set layer.contents.

But cellForRowAtIndexPath is called before willDisplayCell.

https://tech.zalando.de/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/

I don't know why it was working on iOS 9...

Comment: They little bit changed UICollectionView's flow… Maybe it affected your logic…
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/